# No version editor after SVN update with Xcode

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode9, xcode9.2

I use Xcode 9.2 for source control, but when there's a conflict after update, I can't resolve them. The usual two-pane screen appears, but instead of showing the conflicts, I only see the following labels:

- No Files
- No Selection
- No Version Editor

So instead of the good graphical interface, I have to use the command line to resolve my conflicts. What's wrong?

Note: when committing, the version editor appears correctly.

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue ? I think the default merge tool FileMerger is not get invoke in case of SVN ? do you have solution.?

Comment: No, I use command line update in case of conflict. However I always try with XCode first, it resolves most conflicts in XML files. (Storyboards, project files.)

Comment: I read somewhere saying that there may be some compatibility issue with client svn and server svn, so i tried to update the svn but it did not help me out.